# How to check the css change without firing command each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, symfony

I am working on the symfony framework first time.
And web site is highly depend on the CSS , javascript and jquery.
I need to fire this all command each time to test small css change also.

```
app/console server:stop 0.0.0.0:8000
app/console cache:clear 
app/console assets:install 
app/console assetic:dump
app/console server:start 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Is there any other solution to test the css without having all this command each time.
Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling assets and cache. But I think it will involve framework core changes. You can write bat (if on windows) file to do all these commands with single file run.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the css in your source code and not in your web folder, try to install assets with symlinks

```
# make a hard copy of the assets in web/
$ php app/console assets:install

# if possible, make absolute symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink

# if possible, make relative symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink --relative
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `assetic:watch` command:

> […] Fortunately, by using the `assetic:watch` command, assets will be regenerated automatically as they change:
>
> ```
> $ php app/console assetic:watch
> ```

Source: [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment).